# Does anyone have experience wireshark running on Samsung Galaxy Tab? (Verizon)

Tags: networking, data-connection

I need to get detailed request data times on Samsung Galaxy Tab on Verison network.  Does anyone know what is invovled in getting Shark to run on this device?

Comment: [Shark](https://market.android.com/details?id=lv.n3o.shark) doesn't work?  Can you tell us what happens?  (Make sure you aren't running [the native version](https://market.android.com/details?id=lv.n3o.sharknative), I assume that would be more unlikely to work).  Also, your best bet is to contact the developer.

Answer (score 1):

I run `tcpdump` command on my rooted Galaxy tab and capture the output onto SD card. When I have captured enough, I pull the captured file from phone onto a Linux box using `adb pull`  and view the output using Wireshark.

Answer (score -2):

I know how to do it.. With "Linux Installer" software you can install chrooted debian. Then I had to re-build my libpcap and wireshark on GTab because my Overcome kernel did support mmapped packet ring buffer.

I can give detailed instructions if anyone needs...

Oh, I forgot about X11.. You'll have to start X11 vncserver inside chrooted debian on your Android, and then connect to 127.0.0.1 from your Android with your favourite VNC client in order to access "X11".. Let's call this approach X11.99_pre_alpha_8 ))

Comment: Without those detailed instructions, this isn't much of an answer.

Comment: @eforezz So your first step is to remove the Android OS and replace it with Debian Linux? That's a drastic move just to get network timings from a device, and probably totally changes the results you'd get?